# How to set a high res Image in xml?

Tags: android, xml, image

I just need to set a high res image, but wants to know if its possible to set it in xml. I want to be able to set it even if it will be bigger than the mobile screen.

EDIT: I want to add a huge image, so the user will have to scroll it. Something like a map, but need to add clickable areas on it and I only know how to do this in xml. That's why I asked to add the image using xml not in java. But if someone can tell me how to add clickable areas in java. That will do it better, since I already have the image but using java and its able to scroll.

EDIT: Heres where I got the code from : [Anddev.org](http://www.anddev.org/large_image_scrolling_using_low_level_touch_events-t11182.html) I'm using exactly the same code, just with other image.

Comment: Post your related code for scrolling the image. Maybe, someone will give idea regard to your query.

Comment: Should it work if I change this code: bmLargeImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myImage); to BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myImage); or something like that to get the Image from a ImageView in main.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm posting this as an answer, just because it will be easier to post this. (It's not working how I want it to, but I got something) I want to share this so anyone else, who knows how to, can help me out here to find a solution for this one. This is the code

```
package com.example.largeimagescroller;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LargeImageScroller extends Activity {

// Physical display width and height.
private static int displayWidth = 0;
private static int displayHeight = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // displayWidth and displayHeight will change depending on screen
    // orientation. To get these dynamically, we should hook
    // onSizeChanged().
    // This simple example uses only landscape mode, so it's ok to get them
    // once on startup and use those values throughout.
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
            .getDefaultDisplay();
    displayWidth = display.getWidth();
    displayHeight = display.getHeight();

    // SampleView constructor must be constructed last as it needs the
    // displayWidth and displayHeight we just got.
    setContentView(new SampleView(this));       
}

private static class SampleView extends View {
    private static Bitmap bmLargeImage; // bitmap large enough to be
                                        // scrolled
    private static Rect displayRect = null; // rect we display to
    private Rect scrollRect = null; // rect we scroll over our bitmap with
    private int scrollRectX = 0; // current left location of scroll rect
    private int scrollRectY = 0; // current top location of scroll rect
    private float scrollByX = 0; // x amount to scroll by
    private float scrollByY = 0; // y amount to scroll by
    private float startX = 0; // track x from one ACTION_MOVE to the next
    private float startY = 0; // track y from one ACTION_MOVE to the next

    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Destination rect for our main canvas draw. It never changes.
        displayRect = new Rect(0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight);
        // Scroll rect: this will be used to 'scroll around' over the
        // bitmap in memory. Initialize as above.
        scrollRect = new Rect(0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight);

        // Load a large bitmap into an offscreen area of memory.

        bmLargeImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.alienware);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //This code define what to do if you touch the x and y coordinates.
        float x1 = event.getX();
        float y1 = event.getY();

            switch (event.getActionMasked()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (x1>150 & x1<200 & y1>400 & y1<500){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Touched the coordinates.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Remember our initial down event location.
            startX = event.getRawX();
            startY = event.getRawY();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float x = event.getRawX();
            float y = event.getRawY();
            // Calculate move update. This will happen many times
            // during the course of a single movement gesture.
            scrollByX = x - startX; // move update x increment
            scrollByY = y - startY; // move update y increment
            startX = x; // reset initial values to latest
            startY = y;
            invalidate(); // force a redraw
            break;
        }
        return true; // done with this event so consume it
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        // Our move updates are calculated in ACTION_MOVE in the opposite
        // direction
        // from how we want to move the scroll rect. Think of this as
        // dragging to
        // the left being the same as sliding the scroll rect to the right.
        int newScrollRectX = scrollRectX - (int) scrollByX;
        int newScrollRectY = scrollRectY - (int) scrollByY;

        // Don't scroll off the left or right edges of the bitmap.
        if (newScrollRectX < 0)
            newScrollRectX = 0;
        else if (newScrollRectX > (bmLargeImage.getWidth() - displayWidth))
            newScrollRectX = (bmLargeImage.getWidth() - displayWidth);

        // Don't scroll off the top or bottom edges of the bitmap.
        if (newScrollRectY < 0)
            newScrollRectY = 0;
        else if (newScrollRectY > (bmLargeImage.getHeight() - displayHeight))
            newScrollRectY = (bmLargeImage.getHeight() - displayHeight);

        // We have our updated scroll rect coordinates, set them and draw.
        scrollRect.set(newScrollRectX, newScrollRectY, newScrollRectX
                + displayWidth, newScrollRectY + displayHeight);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmLargeImage, scrollRect, displayRect, paint);

        // Reset current scroll coordinates to reflect the latest updates,
        // so we can repeat this update process.
        scrollRectX = newScrollRectX;
        scrollRectY = newScrollRectY;
    }
}
}
```

I rec the application in use. (Since touch events don't work with cpu emulators I did it on my phone)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NrszZoDenXE&feature=youtube_gdata

As you can see its taking the touch, but it moves with the scroll rect, so the question will be: How can I do the touch to stay in the image, so it doesn't move with the scrolling rect?

Thanks

Comment: This is asked in other question, since its out of the main question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676545/big-image-with-scroll-and-clickable-areas

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying for? In android the resolutions are based on like below -

[Screen Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[MultipleResolution](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/MultiResolution/index.html)

Just read out this. Hope these two links enough for your query.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough in the post, sorry about that. I added more info in the edit

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/ldo/view_cache_demo_android) sample code to see how to scroll an image larger than the screen. It also does bitmap caching to speed up drawing of a complex image, and shows how to respond to long-taps and double-taps at any point on the image.

Comment: I just can't get it to run, it crashes.